# Error when using crontab on mac to run python script

Tags: python, python-requests, cron

I want to run a python script using crontab and I keep running into the same Error Message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`. I'm using the following command on my mac terminal:

```
15 21 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /Users/username/Python/Filename.py
```

as I would like to run the Filename Python script every day at 21:15PM.
However, I run into this No module named'requests' even though I have the requests module installed within site-packages under /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages

I've also already made sure that crontab has full disc access in System Preferences. Not sure what to do next and would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: you've got multiple python versions, i don't know exactly what your solution will be, but try using `/usr/local/bin/python3` rather than `/usr/bin/python3` or, this might involve setting your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @Macattack The  /usr/local/bin/python3 worked like a charm - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting @Macattack's answer to mark the question as answered:

try using `/usr/local/bin/python3` rather than `/usr/bin/python3` or, this might involve setting your PYTHONPATH –